# Error in importing to mysql from firebird

Tags: php, mysql, firebird

I created a database called test using phpMyAdmin.

From the command prompt I tried this:

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root test < c:\scriptTest\Telemed.sql
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
 near ''127.0.0.1/gds_db:C:\TELEMED\TELEMED.GDB'   USER 'SYSDBA'
   PAGE_SIZE 4096
   D' at line 1
```

My script file has this

```
/* SQL Manager Lite for InterBase and Firebird 5.2.3.2 */
/* --------------------------------------------------- */
/* Host     : localhost                                */
/* Database : C:\TELEMED\TELEMED.GDB                   */


CREATE DATABASE '127.0.0.1/gds_db:C:\TELEMED\TELEMED.GDB'   USER 'SYSDBA'
PAGE_SIZE 4096
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET NONE;
```

Can someone please let me know what is wrong.

Comment: Such tokens can be enclosed in _backticks_ in SQL, but not in _single quote chars_. Your file syntax is invalid. nothing MySQL can do about that.

Comment: Apart from that: the database name "127.0.0.1/gds_db:C:\TELEMED\TELEMED.GDB" does not really look like a clever thing to do...

Comment: @arkascha In Firebird that identifies the server (127.0.0.1), port (gds_db aka port 3050), and the path to the database (C:\TELEMED\TELEMED.GDB), although it is usually better to use an alias instead of the full path.

Answer (score 1):

The `create database` statement shown is Firebird specific. You will need to translate it to the MySQL equivalent. You can find [the MySQL equivalent in the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html):

> ```
> CREATE {DATABASE | SCHEMA} [IF NOT EXISTS] db_name
>     [create_specification] ...
>
> create_specification:
>     [DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET [=] charset_name
>   | [DEFAULT] COLLATE [=] collation_name
> ```

A simple `create database telemed` might be all you need; although you should carefully consider if you need a default character set or not.

If you already created the database, you can simply remove this statement.

Note that this applies to more things when migrating, eg quoted object names in Firebird are enclosed in double quotes (SQL standard), while MySQL uses backticks. There might also be some differences in syntax and datatypes, etc.